# Problem with OWIN Authorization Server MachineKey Validation

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, owin, machinekey

Hello Guys I'm kind of desperate because I'm not able to figure out what's happening here:
I have been in charge of the upgrade from .NET Framework 4.5.1 to 4.8 of a Legacy Application that no one has changed for several years, it creates bearer tokens using OWIN Authorization and is targeting .NET framework 4.8.
Some other services consume these tokens as bearer tokens, so far I have been able to create the tokens using the Authorization server but when I try to consume them on the services I see that the consumer cannot get the claims successfully.
I have been told that the machine key property must match in both services but despite the two services having the same machine key I keep getting unauthorized responses.

The Auth Server WebConfig Looks like this:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />
    <machineKey validationKey="xxx" decryptionKey="aaa" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
  </system.web>
```

And the Consumer Service Web Config Looks like this:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8">
      <!-- <assemblies>
        <add assembly="AuthComponent2, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=457ad908cac10889, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
        <add assembly="Disney.IAME.Keystone.KeystoneDAL, Version=1.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
        <add assembly="Disney.Keystone.Common.Model.Service, Version=1.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Web.Services3, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
        <add assembly="System.IO.Compression, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies> -->
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8"/>
    <machineKey validationKey="xxx" decryptionKey="aaa" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"/>
  </system.web>
```

If you guys know if there is something missing that I can check I will be very very grateful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I ended up here because after updating to 4.8 I was having issues with services using the "Microsoft.Web.Services3" library.

Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: yes, it was a mismatch between the versions with library.Web.Services3 in the service that creates the tokens with the ones that consumed it.